# Can I view a flash image inside an iframe tag?

Tags: asp.net, html

Can I view a flash image inside an iframe tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just add the Flash to a html-page and set that as the src attribute of the iframe.
Or, just set the Flash-file as the src

Comment: and suppose if i have a written a code using object, param and embed tags then?

Comment: I suppose you have written these codes into a HTML document? Then just set that HTML document as the source of the iframe

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that